# How to echo search results in php

Tags: php, search, mysqli, echo

I've been trying for days to create a simple search engine to search for information in my database. The table is myisam and I get search results when using mysql to search directly in phpmyadmin. So the problem seams to be with the PHP.

When searching all I get is an empty page. I've tried serveral varieations of code I've found in online tutorials, but nothing seems to work. I hope there is a simple solution that I'm too dumb to see, and I hope someone can explain to me how to do this.

```
if(!empty($_POST['search'])){

    $search = $_POST['search'];

    $sqlString = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH (title, about) AGAINST ('$search')";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sqlString) or die("Could not search.." . mysqli_error($dbLink));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($result-> num_rows > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $title = $row['title'];
            echo $title;
        }
    }else{
        echo 'No results';
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your error log?

Comment: Nothing. Just an empty page

Comment: Try `ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!empty($_POST['search'])){

    $search = $_POST['search'];

    $sqlString = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH (title, about) AGAINST ('$search')";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sqlString) or die("Could not search.." . mysqli_error($dbLink));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // remove it 

    if($result-> num_rows > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ // already exist
            $title = $row['title'];
            echo $title;
        }
    }else{
        echo 'No results';
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if($result-> num_rows > 0)
```

To

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
```